# How to fix Glassfish error

Tags: glassfish-4

I am not a good Java programmer yet, but I dream of becoming one. I am practicing building an eCommerce web app with an online Affablebean project using java, my IDE is NetBeans, database is MySQL and MySQL workbench, the server on the Netbeans IDE is Glassfish server 4.

So whenever I try to Ping, to create a connection between Glassfish and MySQL database, I get an error message like this

> Ping Connection Pool failed for AffableBeanPool. Connection could not
>   be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long Please check the
>   server.log for more details.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: How are you creating the connection to your mysql database?

Comment: First of all I right clicked on the glassfish node (while it's running) on on the netbeans IDE, after that, I  chose the view domain admin console. The glassfish interface then appears on the browser where I now click on the JDBC node, I then click on JDBC Connection Pools. After that, the "AffableBeanPool"  option is displayed. So when i click the AffableBeanPool, an interface containing some of the connection pool details appear including the ping button. Naturally clicking the ping button should establish the connection to the Mysql database with a success message. But, I only get error

Comment: here are the last three lines of the messages displayed on my netbeans counsel. Warning:   using.default.ds, Warning:   RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ AffableBeanPool ], Connection could not be allocated because: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long, Severe:   RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/resources/ping-connection-pool.json'; attrs = '{id=AffableBeanPool}'.